# Regex to find sequences of two given characters that alternate

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have written a small program to convert IPv6 addresses to `int`s and back, and I have managed to beat built-in `ipaddress.IPv6Address` in terms of performance.

```py
import re

MAX_IPV6 = 2**128-1
DIGITS = set("0123456789abcdef")

def parse_ipv6(ip: str) -> int:
    assert isinstance(ip, str) and len(ip) <= 39
    segments = ip.lower().split(":")
    l, n, p, count, compressed = len(segments), 0, 7, 0, False
    last = l - 1
    for i, s in enumerate(segments):
        assert count <= 8 and len(s) <= 4 and not set(s) - DIGITS
        if not s:
            if i in (0, last):
                continue
            assert not compressed
            p = l - i - 2
            compressed = True
        else:
            n += int(s, 16) << p*16
            p -= 1
        count += 1
    return n

def to_ipv6(n: int, compress=False) -> str:
    assert isinstance(n, int) and 0 <= n <= MAX_IPV6
    ip = '{:032_x}'.format(n).replace('_', ':')
    if not compress:
        return ip
    return re.sub('0{1,3}([\da-f]+)', '\\1', ip)
```

I am currently trying to implement compression, namely find the longest run of two alternating characters 0 and :, and replace the first occurrence of it with ::.

For example, given this address: `'abcd:0:ef12::a:0:0'`, `parse_ipv6('abcd:0:ef12::a:0:0')` gives this number: `228362408209208931942454293848746098688`, but `to_ipv6(parse_ipv6('abcd:0:ef12::a:0:0'), 1)` gives this: `'abcd:0:ef12:0:0:a:0:0'`.

As you see the result is not properly compressed.

In short I want a regex pattern to be used with `re.findall` to find sequences like `[':0', ':0:', ':0:0:', '0:', '0:0:', '0:0:0:']`.

I have Google searched this, and found many questions on this site with similar phrasing, but none of them solves my problem.

I have tried this regex:

```
In [277]: ip
Out[277]: 'abcd:0:ef12:0:0:a:0:0'

In [278]: re.findall('((:0)+)|((0:)+)', ip)
Out[278]: [(':0', ':0', '', ''), (':0:0', ':0', '', ''), (':0:0', ':0', '', '')]
```

I was expecting `[':0:', ':0:0:', ':0:0']`.

How to fix this?

---

Using the correct regex I updated my code to this:

```
EMPTY = re.compile(r':?\b(?:0\b:?)+')

def to_ipv6(n: int, compress:bool=False) -> str:
    assert isinstance(n, int) and 0 <= n <= MAX_IPV6
    ip = '{:039_x}'.format(n).replace('_', ':')
    if not compress:
        return ip
    ip = ':'.join(s.lstrip('0') if s != '0000' else '0' for s in ip.split(':'))
    longest = max(EMPTY.findall(ip), key=len, default='')
    if len(longest) > 2:
        ip = ip.replace(longest, '::', 1)
    return ip
```

It correctly compresses the given example:

```
In [334]: to_ipv6(228362408209208931942454293848746098688, True)
Out[334]: 'abcd:0:ef12::a:0:0'
```

I stopped using `re.sub('0{1,3}([\da-f]+)', '\\1', ip)` because somehow it took 8 microseconds and some to complete. The comprehension is faster.

---

The original code in this question doesn't actually work, the parser correctly parses valid IPv6 addresses but fails to identify invalid IPv6 addresses, thus gives incorrect output when it should raise exceptions.

And the formatter also doesn't work, it gives incorrect outputs as well, namely it can sometimes fail to choose the longest consecutive empty fields, which is wrong. And will raise exceptions when the address cannot be compressed.

***DO NOT USE MY CODE IN YOUR PRODUCTION CODE***, it is buggy and not well-tested.

That said, I have fixed every bug I can find and made the code raise exceptions for all invalid inputs I can think of, a long time ago. But I didn't bother update the code in this question. Because I am lazy and there might still be edge cases I didn't catch.

And today this question received an upvote so long after it was posted, an upvote it didn't deserve. So I felt compelled to update the question and edit the code, I fixed the formatter and not the parser, because the parser became too long, and I meant to discourage its use (well I would keep using my code, but nobody else should use it).

Comment: Because you're [using groups with `re.findall`...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) how about [`:?\b(?:0\b:?)+`](https://regex101.com/r/fhrhjD/1) (used a [non capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) for repetition in this pattern, `\b` is a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to prevent matching `00`, `a0`,`0a`...)

Comment: @bobblebubble Your example doesn't work. After removing the two `\b`s, this `':?(?:0:?)+'` works. But after removing `\b`s it will match `'00'`

Comment: It worked [like this Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYsrs0DBVkE9MSk5xcrAKjXN0AhIGVglgkh1Lq6i1GKgdFGqXlpmXkpiTo5GkZKVfUyShr2VQUySlb2mtpKOQmaBJldBUWZeiQZQteb//wA) for me: `re.findall(r":?\b(?:0\b:?)+", ip)`

Comment: @bobblebubble Yes, it works, after I add the prefix r like you did. Somehow without `r` it doesn't work. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: What *is* the desired "properly compressed" result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Python manual -> `re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

> If multiple groups are present, return a list of tuples of strings matching the groups. Non-capturing groups do not affect the form of the result.

To match the desired sequences and prevent matching such as `:00:` `a0:` `0a:` here an idea.

```
res = re.findall(r":?\b(?:0\b:?)+", ip)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fhrhjD/1) or a [Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYsrs0DBVkE9MSk5xcrAKjXN0AhIGVglgkh1Lq6i1GKgdFGqXlpmXkpiTo5GkZKVfUyShr2VQUySlb2mtpKOQmaBJldBUWZeiQZQteb//wA)

It matches an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `:` followed by a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), followed by a [repeated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [`(?:` non capturing group `)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) *one or more times* which contains `0` at a *word boundary* followed by an *optional* colon.

If you don't want to match `0` without colon, another variant: [`(?::0\b)+:?|(?:\b0:)+(?:0\b)?`](https://regex101.com/r/6tFYlG/1)

Answer (score 0):

A solution **this** simple worked for me:

```py
re.findall('[:0]+', ip)
```

Hope that's what you were looking for. :)

Comment: It's true it will work, but it will also match  `'00'` and `'::'` which are not permitted.

Comment: Hmm... pretty sure you can just filter the list to remove those, but I suppose you want pure Regex. 

Comment: This will even report the `0:` in `120:45`